# Watcher does not trigger

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 with options API.

As shown in the below posted code, in `watch` object, I monitor the changes occurred to `isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon`. In the method `onDigitizePolygon` I change the value of `isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon`, however, when the value of the latter is changed,
the computed property `compPropsIsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon` is executed indicating the change of `isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon`, but the watcher `isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon` is never executed, in other words, the log statments inside that watcher are
never executed.

To solve this issue, I also tried the following

```
watch: {
    'isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.value'(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.info(infoTag, 'isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.newVal:', newVal)
        console.info(infoTag, 'isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.oldVal:', oldVal)

        if (newVal == true && oldVal == false) {
            console.log(debugTag, 'removeDigitized()');
        } else if (newVal == false && oldVal == true) {
            console.log(debugTag, 'digitize()');
        }
    },
},
```

but it also did not work

Why does the watcher does not trigger and how to fix it?

***app.vue***:

```
<template>
    <button id="idBtnDigitizePolygon" class="clsBtnDigitizePolygon" @click="onDigitizePolygon()" :disabled="isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled">
        {{ compPropsIsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon }}
    </button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

let isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon = ref(true);

let debugTag = 'D.ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue::';
let infoTag = 'I.ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue::';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            btnDigitizePolyhonState: this.isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled,
        };
    },
    props: {
        isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },
    watch: {
        isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.info(infoTag, 'isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.newVal:', newVal)
            console.info(infoTag, 'isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.oldVal:', oldVal)

            if (newVal == true && oldVal == false) {
                console.log(debugTag, 'removeDigitized()');
            } else if (newVal == false && oldVal == true) {
                console.log(debugTag, 'digitize()');
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        compPropsIsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon() {
            if (isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.value == true) {
                return 'digitize'
            } else {
                return 'clear'
            }
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onDigitizePolygon() {
            isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.value = !isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.value;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please _learn something_ from the edits people make to your posts. Being able to correctly identify what even is code would be a good  starting point.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i did not get actually your point. do you that i should next time i post a question to pay attention to, for example, capitalization of the wording used..is that what you ment please?!

Comment: I've had to change the same things at least three times, you can see the details in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76969745/revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are currently trying to use ref() with the composition property on the Options API. If you fix your syntax the code will work properly. I hope I could help.

As an example code:

```js
<template>
  <button
    id="idBtnDigitizePolygon"
    class="clsBtnDigitizePolygon"
    :disabled="isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled"
    @click="onDigitizePolygon()"
  >
    {{ compPropsIsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>

let debugTag = 'D.ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue::';
let infoTag = 'I.ButtonDigitizePolygon.vue::';

export default {
  props: {
    isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    compPropsIsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon() {
      if (this.isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.value === true) {
        return 'digitize';
      } else {
        return 'clear';
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.info(infoTag, 'isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.newVal:', newVal);
      console.info(infoTag, 'isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon.oldVal:', oldVal);

      if (newVal === true && oldVal === false) {
        console.log(debugTag, 'removeDigitized()');
      } else if (newVal === false && oldVal === true) {
        console.log(debugTag, 'digitize()');
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onDigitizePolygon() {
      this.isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon = !this.isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

or you can use ref() in setup function like this:

```js
setup() {
    const isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon = ref(false);
    return {
      isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon,
    };
  }
```

Comment: i am using options api not composition api?!

Comment: would you please explain why your approach works and mine did not work. you declared `isToggleBtnLabelDigitizePolygon` in data() while i declared it as regular `ref` what is the difference please

Comment: well if you want to use ref(), you have to declare in the setup() and expose it.

Comment: But I am using options api as shown in my questions. And as far as I know, in options api there is no ‘setup’

Comment: You are right but then you can not use ref(). As mention in official [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html).

Comment: I already answered your first post and a similar question. The logic in all of them is the same, if you act according to your documentation, you will not have a problem.